# php files not working in mamp after uninstall wordpress locally

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost, mamp

I am having problems with php executing in mamp. Html is working fine, but php is showing up as text.

I did have php files working fine so I know it isn’t the code.

I installed wordpress locally, created a database but then decided I wanted to revert back to php files.

I deleted the database I created in php my admin, and deleted the wordpress files in htdocs.

However, now my originally php files do not work in localhost.

When I go to localhost, the page I created in wordpress appears - I have cleared my cache.

I also deleted mamp, and reinstalled it  - but have the same problem.

I also downloaded XAMP – and php files do not work either.

I am not very experienced with server issues, I cannot figure out what I have done wrong and it is very frustrating.

I am working on mac.

Would welcome any suggestions!

Thanks

Comment: You are saving your php files with the `.php` extension and visiting `localhost:8888/` in your browser?

Comment: yes all files are saved .php - the files were working fine before I installed wordpress and these files were not changed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your scripts work, but are showing up as text..Are you sure that PHP is added after < ?.
just double check that

Comment: Yes the php is coded fine, as they were working fine before I installed wordpress and these files were not changed at all. Thanks.